# If $X$ is Uniform$[0,1]$, does $1-X$ converge in distribution to $X$?

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

Example 1.1.5 in http://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Asymptotic%20Statistics%20-%20Lecture%20Notes.pdf

Here is the example and the question:
$X$ ~ $U[0, 1]$, and $X_n = X$ for all n, and $Y_n = X$ for n odd and $Y_n = 1 - X$ for n even. I am confused if $Y_n$ converges to $X_n$ in distribution.

I know it is clearly not, but here is what I deduced by definition of convergence in distribution:
$$|F_{Y_n}(t) - F_{X_n}(t)| = |P(Y_n \leq t) - P(X \leq t)| = |P(X > 1-t) - P(X \leq t)| = |1-(1-t)-t| = 0$$

I think there must be something wrong here, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

All you need for convergence in distribution is the convergence of the CDFs at every continuity point of the limiting distribution. This clearly holds; in fact, not only do the distributions converge, they are all equal. All the random variables in the sequence are equal in distribution.

Comment: So my deduce is right? The lecture notes is wrong? It is my first time to really realize the difference between convergence in distribution and other modes of convergence.

Comment: @XingzheHe The lecture notes states that both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge in distributon to uniform distribution. And the pair $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not converge! You deduce the first fact only.

Comment: @NCh What does it mean by 'the pair $(X_n,Y_n)$does not converge'?

Comment: @XingzheHe Joint distribution of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ does not converge. Pointwise limit of $F_{X_n,Y_n}(t,s)=P(X_n\leq t, Y_n\leq s)$ does not exist.

Comment: @NCh Thank you so much!